# Cannot install utop on RHEL 5.0

Tags: ocaml, opam

Having successfully installed opam and having switched to 4.01.0 version of compiler I am struggling to install utop. Installation is failing at 'conf-ncurses.1' step.

Running 'opam depext' does not reveal much, saying that 'no extra dependencies' need to be installed. Switching to latest stable compiler, and then installing utop fails with the same problem. The *.err and *.out files are empty, hence not revealing any problem.

On my box I also have ncurses-devl and pkgconfig installed (see rpm output below)

Below is the screenshot of what I can see (hopefully it give us enough information). Any ideas where to look at ?:

[Screehshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRcLr.png)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, SO is not an issue tracker and it is better to report this issue to the package maintainers. The following command will reveal URLs for the issue trackers:

```
 opam show conf-ncurses | grep bug-reports
 opam show utop | grep bug-reports
```

Second, your output is not at sync with what I'm seeing in the `opam-repository`. At the current HEAD there is no check `pkg-config ncurses` at all, as it was [removed](https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/commit/aabd225cb2f1c6e836cea7bb956fb944c4073731) three days ago. So, if you indeed have `ncurses-devel` package installed, then you need just to update opam, with

```
 opam update
```

Comment: ivg, thanks a lot; this has helped !

all I had to was to run: 
1. opam update 
2. opam upgrade 
3. opam install utop